# Read contents of Blob in Javascript websocket message

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm writing WebSocket based clients servers.

I want to send raw binary data that is then decoded by the client.

My problem is two-fold:

- while doing manipulations on binary data in c++ (the language I'm writing the servers in) is straight forward, it seems hard in Javascript.
- I have found that you can use `ArrayBuffer`s and `UInt8Array`s to do most of the manipulations, and that works fine for sending messages.
- My problem is that when I try receiving the messages if I declare the message as binary on the server side, it shows up as a `Blob` on the client. I have tried converting the Blob to an `ArrayBuffer` like so:

```
ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    var data = null;
    data = await new Response(evt.data).arrayBuffer();
}
```

But this gives me the error:

`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators`

It seems that this method is asynchronous, and while I'm sure I could do it this way, it doesn't really seem that good in the first place.

I have realized that sending the data as the text makes `evt.data` appear as a string, which makes me believe that I can use a JSON format for the packets instead of a binary one.

I really don't want to use JSON though, as some of the packets will be full of a lot of information and I'm scared it will add unnecessary bloat.

I think what I really want is just to be able to read the `evt.data` as an `ArrayBuffer`, because it seems like that would be the most performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the then method of the promise

```
new Response(evt.data).arrayBuffer().then(buffer=> {
//here you have the buffer
})
```

[then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)
[arrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer)

Note: The await can be used inside functions declared with async keyword.